# VBA Function - Argument Not Optional (Separating Blocks of Text)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Macro6()

Dim rngW As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rngW = Range("W1", Range("W65536").End(xlUp))
For Each cell In rngW
If cell.Value = "Y" Then

Rows.Select
Range.Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown


End Sub
```

I want to put add a blank row above each "Y" in column W that I find in my entire excel sheet. This will help me separate chunks of data. I keep getting "Compile Error: Argument not Optional". What gives?

Comment: You are missing the `End If` and `Next cell`

Answer (score 2):

As Scott Craner points out you are missing closing statements for `If` and `Next`.

Also, when inserting or deleting rows, you will need to loop backwards through the row set.

See code below:

```
Sub Macro6()

Dim lRow as Long
lRow = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i as Long

For i = lRow to 1 Step -1

   if Range("W" & i).Value = "Y" Then Range("W" & i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I was two seconds from submitting nearly the exact same thing.

Comment: The only difference was I put `With ActiveSheet` for the parent and used `Rows.Count` instead of hard coded row.

Comment: @ScottCraner - fair points on both accounts. I didn't feel like tweaking too much! Depends on the mood how deeply I answer a question :). I did change to Rows.Count since it's a way better method.

Comment: Thanks so much gang!!

Comment: I just wanted you know why you beat me. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner easy: you answered in a comment, that's why ;-)